# Can I get an email's attachment filenames as crawled properties from the SharePoint 2010 .MSG IFilter?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, ifilter

I would like to retrieve a .msg file's attachment names as a managed property so we can filter on it. Does SharePoint 2010's MSG IFilter expose this info?

If not, does anyone know of a 3rd-party IFilter that would?

Thanks.